# Up and Down Voting a Moderator

Tags: discussion, support, design

Do moderators know when you are down or up voting all their answers? Is it anonymity for all?

Comment: Downvoting takes rep from the voter as well as the votee. (Spell check says votee is unknown to it :-) ). If a person was making multiple downvotes in a day then this would be detectable. If a specific person's rep was analysed carefully it may give an indication of their voting behaviour but not their "targets". I occasionally receive clusters of downvotes on a range of answers for no apparently good reason*. This gives the impression that it is a single person at work - but no guarantee. [[[* My answers never **deserve** downvotes :-)  :-)  :-)  :-)   ]]].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope, moderators don't know who votes on their posts.

We can get access to some aggregate information about votes to use for identifying fraudulent behavior. For example, if two (or more) accounts are suspected of belonging to the same person, we have a tool that reveals whether there is a suspicious pattern in how the accounts are voting. But the information we get never extends to the level of individual posts. In other words, the tools never show us who voted on a particular post, whether it's our own post or someone else's.

For what it's worth, even if we did know, we wouldn't care. (There are some cases where we can *guess* who cast a vote, using the same logic that anyone else might use, and we don't care about those.)

Comment: Will it be an issue to down vote all of someones answer because they do it to you?

Comment: @Jen, YES. Voting should never be used as retaliation. Stay above the fray- it defeats the usefulness of the entire site for every user (and future users). Think of your votes as an exercise in the scientific method, where truth is foremost, and grudges matter not.

Comment: @Jen just to officially confirm what theNamesCross said, yes, that is very much against the rules. Voting in that way normally gets detected and reversed automatically. It's also possible that an account might be suspended from the site for that sort of behavior. (And if someone did it to you, that just means both you and the other person are breaking the rules, and both of you are susceptible to the punishment.)

Comment: @Jen: I think most people here have a fairly simple voting pattern: they up-vote high quality content and they down-vote low quality content. Try to produce high quality content and you will receive lots of up-votes. Yes, it is that simple.